# VS-Code: How to sort imports in specific order to go along with InteliJ

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, import

I am working in a team which mostly uses InteliJ. There imports get automatically sorted after the path. So "@namespace" goes first then less nested imports "./" > "../../" and on the same level its alphabetical.

Until now I used the "source.organizeImports" setting from VSCode which sorted the imports for named and default imports. This cant be customized as stated in another SO question and is not listed here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_organize-imports

I tried the VSC extension vsc-organize-imports but that doesnt have that option either. I would like to avoid to configure and run esLint to fix my import order. Any other suggestions, setting or extension I could try?

Comment: This ESLint plugin can do the sorting via the `--fix` command to ESLint: [`eslint-plugin-import`](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import)

Comment: Yeah, but you can only do prettier or eslint --fix. Both together is usually not a good idea. I have used this on projects where eslint is used for formatting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In another project I have taken another look into this matter. The only solution is to turn the VSC organize import feature off and let the formatter/linter do the work. As I dont like my linter on autofix and I generally think its the job of the formatter and everyone should have one heres my solution:

- In a TS project I used **prettier-plugin-organize-imports**. This prettier plugin mimicks the formatting order of the organize imports feature, so its basically the same. Very nice, except it has a TS  peer dependency.

Therefore a second solution for JS projects:

- Use the prettier plugin **prettier-plugin-import-sort**. This plugin needs you to add an order style of your choice with it. But it supports vanilla JS

As mentioned I have also found rules for eslint with an autofix, but I dont like that solution. The above packages fix the problem if you are using prettier.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a vs-code extension [sort-imports](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amatiasq.sort-imports) to achieve the sorting of imports.

Comment: As I stated in my question my colleagues do not use VSCode, so a VSCode Plugin is of little use.

Comment: not just that, but it is also extremely limited. It only supports very specific "styles" of importing, but OP was looking for a specific order, they can define.